# How should I name my menu's links?

Tags: website-design, navigation, names

Suppose a conceptual web application where a user is supposed to:

- Choose a meeting in a list (that would take place in a near future) and possibly participate to one.
- Create its own meeting, waiting for potential participants.

So the menu would contain two links:

- One for listing the meeting that DON'T concern the user yet.
- One for listing the meetings the user participates in or creates himself.

How should I name those links?

I was thinking about:

- "**Meetings actu**"  (reference to actuality)  including only meetings user's not participating yet and not created by himself, but can interest him.
- "**My meetings**" including current meetings user's concerned and the full user's historical regarding them.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**actu**" doesn't mean anything to me, it is probably too technical/ambiguous a term to use.

I would have one section called **Meetings**, then within this section have a filter option to be able to only show **Created by me, Attending, Not attending**, etc.

From the front page you could have a button next to Meetings saying **Meetings (Attending)**, for example, this would then navigate to the Meetings section but with the Attending filter preselected.

**UPDATE:**
Your choice of filters and the way you display them on the page need to be thought out thoroughly. first make a list of all possible filtered lists you need to cater for. This will then help you design the filter.

Comment: I totally agree with this point of view. So there were two strategies: 1) Create another dedicated link called "My Meetings", or rather 2) apply a filter on the main list page, so that the menu still remain to only one link: "Meetings". I like this latter.

Comment: It's more touchy to find a similar word for "Attending" filter in French, without altering the meaning. Indeed, attending and attendee are represented by the exact same word in French: "Participant". I think it would confuse people interpreting this filter: Does it mean "show me only Meetings already having some participants", or "show me only the meetings I'm participating or participated).

Comment: A direct replacement for an 'Attending' filter, could be 'Participating In'

Comment: Thanks for the update. "Participating in" has not such a similar and clean equivalent in French. I think I would choose the equivalent of "I'm participating in" => "J'y participe". IMHO, it would avoid any confusion with other filters relating participants like "None participant" (currently empty meeting).

Comment: like I say, the filters you offer are dependant on you and what you want to offer. with regards to translations, I can't really comment, I can't speak French ;)

Comment: Yes :), you're right with the fact that I should start by listing all filters and display them in the app to analyse the possible user misinterpretation. Thanks a lot :) French is so bad ;)

Comment: @Mik378 just noticed the way that this site organises its badges page is similar to what I was getting at. They use tabs for the filters (all, earned, unearned, etc) http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges Replace Badges for Meetings and change the tabs to the filters you want and you can steal it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use as simple and well-understood words as possible.

What about **My meetings** and **All**?

The "All" list would include my own meetings as well. It could be indicated that I am already participating in a meeting, but I see no reason to sort them out from the All list.

**UPDATE:**

From your comment it sounds like the "Actu" list might be a "Suggestions" or "Available" list. If you have another place for showing All, then the "Actu" list might not have to show them, although I would still find it odd to show all but mine.

***If*** this list is like a feed shared among several users, this could be a place to communicate to me as a user how and where my posts appears to other users. Just like I see my own Questions here on StackExchange, while I have to go to my profile to see my activity.

It all depends on what metaphors you choose to use through out the app. If the concept you choose draws on apps or websites the users are familiar with, adopting the terms from there might make them more graspable, even if less describing. And in either case, the title does not have to say it all, you might add a title on top of the lists, clarifying the purpose of the list.

- **Available**, **Today** or **Suggestions** and **Confirmed**, **Booked** or **Attending** (metaphor: ticket booking)
- **Public** and **< username >** (calendar)
- **Home** and **< username >** (facebook)
- **Inbox** and **Attending** (email/calendar)

If you are on a stage of *what* you want to show, then naming it will be easier when you got the concepts sorted out. If you already done that, then perhaps a few wireframes or screenshots will make the question easier to answer.

Comment: Nice point. I agree with the fact that "All" should contain my own meetings as well. However, some early-adopters told me: "When I'm participating to the meeting A, I do not want to see them in the common list (the ALL list). I would like another link called "My meetings", where I see all the meetings, even those in the past". What do you think?

Comment: I am curios why the early-adopter wanted it that way? I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to read the update. Some (a few) early-adopters thought that it would be boring to display the meetings that they have already accepted in the "public" list. I will read your answer in detail :) Thanks a lot